# synonyms for the word "valence" per the paragraph cited

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms

Currently undertaking an MBA programme. The present subject is Leadership. Using a textbook by Hughes, Ginnett and Curphy: Leadership; Enhancing the lessons of experience. (2012, 7th ed.)

The sentence reads:

> By manifesting the appropriate leadership behaviours, the leader can increase followers' effort-to-expectancies, performance-to-reward expectancies, or **valences** of the outcome.

I understand the concept of *valency* from chemistry - the combining power of an atom or ion in terms of the number of Hydrogen atoms or equivalents - but do not quite know what the authors intended by using the word *valence* in the short paragraph cited.

So what does *valences* mean here? Are there any synonyms that could have been used to better, more illuminating effect?

Comment: Frankly, I doubt even the authors knew what their jargon meant! What is an "effort-to-expectancy"?

Comment: Perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_%28psychology%29

Comment: I tend to agree with you, Andrew

Answer (score 1):

In chemistry ***valency*** is the power or capacity of certain elements to combine with or displace a greater or less number of hydrogen (or other) atoms.  The word comes from Latin (ante- and post-classical) *valentia* - vigour, capacity.

***Valence*** is used especially in psychology to mean emotional force or significance, specifically the feeling of attraction or repulsion with which an individual invests an object or event.

> 1935   D. K. Adams & K. E. Zener tr. K. Lewin Dynamic Theory of Personality ii. 51   *A certain object or event..is experienced as an attraction (or repulsion)... We shall say of such objects that they possess a ‘valence’*.
>
> 1952   W. J. H. Sprott Social Psychol. ii. 30   *The piece of chocolate is said to have ‘positive valence’ for the child and exercises an attractive force*.

The OP quote is clearly 'specialist' verging on arcane.  'Valance' here seems to refer to 'group dynamics', 'interactions', 'power and influence of members on each others' behaviours'.